# Python script to align object to edge or two vertex coordinates

Tags: python, objects, transforms, edges

I want to align an object to an edge via Python.
I have an edge in the 3D space, the edge has a rotation, euler or quaternion, like a 3d object, but this edge is part of an object.
I want to copy the rotation of the edge to a external object (like a cylinder).

This seams like what I want, but the result doesn't work.
[Align Object to Vector using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/align-object-to-vector-using-python)

Comment: I've found the solution.
To align to edge direction, you can use the script in this link:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/align-object-to-vector-using-python
But for the vector you must use "Vector=Vector2-Vector1" where the Vector1 e Vector2 are the coordinates in vector of the vertes of the edge.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. To align to edge direction, you can use the script in this link: [Align Object to Vector using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/align-object-to-vector-using-python)

But for the vector you must use `Vector = Vector2 - Vector1` where the Vector1 e Vector2 are the coordinates in vector of the verts of the edge.