# How to precisely rotate object to align with 3D cursor via Python script?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, objects, transforms

I would like to rotate my object, which is a simple rod, so it PRECISELY align with the 3D cursor.
Here are some images showing what I mean:

[image: Before rotation]

[image: After rotation]

I wish it to be precise so I asked for the python script, but showing me how to calculate this is also very helpful.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can use the `Vector.angle` function to find the angle between an arbitrary axis vector (like the Z axis "up" vector), and the 3D cursor. This will provide you the angle you need to rotate your object to align it with the cursor in that specific axis.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

curloc  = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location # Cursor location
up      = Vector((0,0,1)) # Positive Z axis
right   = Vector((1,0,0)) # Positive X axis
forward = Vector((0,1,0)) # Positive Y axis

o = bpy.context.object    # Active object

# Calculate angle between up and cursor vectors and set as Y rotation
o.rotation_euler.y = up.angle( curloc )
```

Notice that in the example above I'm aligning the object with the cursor on the Y axis specifically. You can change this by replacing the axis letter on `o.rotation_euler`, to align with a different axis.

Comment: This looks a bit dodgy.. doubt  this works for cursor locations in the -x quadrants or when there is a lot of "depth" on the 3d cursor.?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work properly with negative axis values. Could probably get around this by inverting the angle in these cases, but a more general solution is likely better.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the 3d cursor to lie exactly on the z axis of your object, in which case can use methods outlined in this answer [Align Object to Vector using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/align-object-to-vector-using-python?rq=1)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from bpy import context

obj = context.object
scene = context.scene
loc, rot, scale = obj.matrix_world.decompose()
vec = scene.cursor_location - loc

# object axis to align with vector vec
z = Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0))

q = z.rotation_difference(vec)
obj.matrix_world = Matrix.Translation(loc) * q.to_matrix().to_4x4()
obj.scale = scale
```

If you want to rotate using the view ( equiv of bpy.ops.object.rotate(angle, axis, GLOBAL) ) give a hoy and will edit together.

Answer (score 1):

**Origin of the mesh and 3d cursor coordinates**

First you have to know the x,y,z coordinates of the *origin* of the mesh and of the 3d *cursor*.

The coordinates of the 3d **cursor** you find:

[image]

THe coordinates of the origin of the mesh you find:

1. First <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, *cursor to selected*:

[image]

2. Read the coordinates in the same way as for the 3d cursor.

**Mesh rotation**

Next, onsider this schematic:

[image]

Angle *theta* can be calculated with arctan(dy/dx), where

- dy = abs(y_3dcursor - y_originmesh)
- dx = abs(x_3dcursor - x_originmesh)

Enter topview with <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>

1. Now add a plane (with the 3d cursor located on the origin of the mesh and re-enter the coordinates of the 3d cursor's original location
2. Change transform-orientation to normal:

[image]

3. Turn the plan around the z-axis theta degrees with <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd> and enter theta (correct negative or positive sign if necessary) such that either the red x-axis or green y-axis points to the 3d cursor:

[image]

4. In the right side toolbar of the 3d view, add new custom *transform orientation* (highlighted):

[image]

5. Select the new transfomation-orientation:

[image]

6. Select the mesh

[image]

7. Angle phi can be calculated with arctan(dz/r), where

   - dz = abs(z_3dcursor - z_originmesh)
   - r = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2)
8. With the mesh selected, then rotate the mesh around the axis **that does not point to the 3d cursor** which is the y-axis in this example, press <kbd>R</kbd>, **twice** <kbd>Y</kbd> and enter '90-phi':

[image]

9. Which results in the mesh rotated to the 3d cursor:

[image]

Comment: I explained the mathematical way of calculation, but maybe this helps you with writing your script