# Choose arbitrary vector as "up_axis" for camera with "Track To"-constraint

Tags: python, scripting, camera

**Hello guys!**

To programmatically add a constraint to the camera in my scene, I do the following:

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils import Quaternion
import random

camera = bpy.data.objects.get("Camera")
target_object = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")

camera.constraints.clear()
track_to = camera.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')
track_to.target = target_object
track_to.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
track_to.up_axis = 'UP_Y' # <- is it possible to change this somehow?
```

This works fine and the camera correctly follows the cube. However, for my task, I need the camera constraint to randomly change the selected `up_axis` to an arbitrary vector on the plane, which lies orthogonal to the `track_axis` every time I run the script. I hope Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogTWX.png) clarifies my goal. Is there a simple way to do this?

I already tried:

```py
loc, rot, scale = camera.matrix_world.decompose()
new_rot = Quaternion(rot.axis, random.uniform(-180, 180))
camera.constraints.clear() # <- seems to be required for the rotation changes to take effect
camera.rotation_quaternion = new_rot
```

But this approach causes the camera to entirely lose focus on the cube.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Wanted functionality.]

Comment: Is the script supposed to be run for each frame?

Comment: Hello @lemon!
The script will be used to generate an arbitrary amount of renderings. Every possible rotation of the camera, as shown in the figure, must be equally likely (uniform distribution), but there is no need to "animate" something or "to call the script for each frame".

The workflow should be as follows:

add "Track To" constraint to camera -> randomly change camera position -> randomly change rotation around "Track axis" -> take photo.

This should be repeated as often as the user wants it to do so.

Comment: So do you really need the track to constraint? Why don't you align the cam to the target by the script itself?

Comment: Could do it using this approach for instance: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73013/19156

Comment: @lemon I suppose I don't necessarily need the constraint. But it seems very comfortable to me, that I don't have to align the camera by myself every time I change the position of the object or the camera itself. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: At first though, a constraint is a constraint and won't let you do what you want here... so...

Comment: Thank you for the tip, @lemon. The linked answer gave me an idea. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127440/105192) does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Align to and roll on vector.**

[image]

In a related question showed the math of aligning an object to the view as defined by the camera, instead here will align the camera -Z axis to the object and roll the camera randomly around it.

- Vector `v2` is the global direction camera faces
- Vector `v1` is the vector defined looking at camera from object
- The rotational difference between the two gives us the rotation required to make camera point at object
- Change the space to rotate about the origin point of the object in global space.
- Make another random rotation matrix to roll about this point about the axis `v1`

Test script (often would use context object for cube and scene camera for camera, to avoid need to edit and run, rather simply change active object)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import radians
from random import random

camera = bpy.data.objects.get("Camera")
target_object = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")

cmw = camera.matrix_world
tmw = target_object.matrix_world

v1 = tmw.translation - cmw.translation
v2 = cmw.to_3x3() @ Vector((0, 0, -1))

R = (Matrix.Translation(cmw.translation) @ 
    v2.rotation_difference(v1).to_matrix().to_4x4() @ 
    Matrix.Rotation(random() * radians(360), 4, v1.normalized()) @ 
    Matrix.Translation(-cmw.translation))

camera.matrix_world = R @ cmw
```

Possibly worth mentioning, could do same by rolling first on `v2`

```
R = (Matrix.Translation(cmw.translation) @ 
     Matrix.Rotation(random() * radians(360), 4, v2.normalized()) @ 
     v2.rotation_difference(v1).to_matrix().to_4x4() @        
     Matrix.Translation(-cmw.translation))
```

**Make a dolly**

Another approach would be make an empty, parent camera to empty. Track the empty to the cube.  Simply roll the camera using the z axis.

Examples.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/130456/15543

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176762/15543

Comment: Thank you very much, @batFINGER. That's exactly what I needed.