# BMesh create rotation

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I am creating a bmesh from a list of points in 3d space (e.g. a circle):

```
def extrude_mesh(self, context, bm):
    if context.scene.extrude_mesh:

        dir = self.shape.get_dir() * context.scene.draw_distance * 2

        if self.shape.is_extruded():
            dir = self.shape.get_dir() * self.shape.extrusion

        r = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=bm.faces[:])
        verts = [e for e in r['geom'] if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
        bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=dir, verts=verts)
```

## .............

```
def create_object(self, context):

    # Create a mesh and an object and 
    # add the object to the scene collection
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("MyMesh")
    obj  = bpy.data.objects.new("MyObject", mesh)

    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.select_set(state=True)

    # Create a bmesh and for list of vertices
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh) 

    for v in self.shape.vertices:
        bm.verts.new(v)

    bm.verts.index_update()

    bm.faces.new(bm.verts)

    self.extrude_mesh(context, bm)

    bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
    bm.free()
```

The new object that is created has the rotation `(0,0,0)`, but I want the rotation to be the direction of the face from which I created the bmesh.

P.S. Just saw that I could just set the `rotation_euler` to the direction of the shape?

P.P.S. Tried it but doesnt solve the problem. Any ideas? The orientation of the mesh is alright but the rotation of the objects is `(0,0,0)` because it is created like this.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/align-object-to-vector-using-python

Comment: @batFINGER: Ok, I see, but the rotation in 3d space of my extruded object is correct, I just want the rotation in the view to be reflected as rotation of the object but it is set to '(0,0,0)'